# HTTPS communication problem between docker containers

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, nginx, https

**Specific description**: After my page is loaded via HTTPS, I am trying to log in. While performing action that triggers POST to web api, there is web browser (chrome) error: This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources.

**Background**: I am using docker with three containers: backend, frontend and db, in bridged network. Everythig was okay until I decided to configure HTTPS.

Frontend - Nginx is working as reverse proxy, and web server for angular app, configured for HTTPS only.
Backend - .net core 3.0 web api, works on unsecured HTTP 5000 port with headers forwarding on.

Nginx config, at least part I find interesing in terms of this problem:

```
    upstream web-api {
    server backend:5000;
}

server {
    server_name <myDomainHere>.xx www.<myDomainHere>.xx;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass         http://web-api;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
```

I have read, that to achive  my site working in HTTPS I have to configure certificates (which is already done) on nginx container, and set it as reverse proxy. I have also changed my angular config, so calls are made to nginx.

**My investigation:**
I have created fake GET endpoint, I was reaching it by browser like https://mydomain.xx/api/GetEndpoint , and it worked, I recived the response. Nginx was able to recognize location rules, rewrite headers, and forwarded GET as it is expected by reverse proxy. It looks like nginx has problem forwarding with POST request only.

**Summary:**
I have tried to describe my whole environment, because maybe question how to forward POST by nginx is wrong question. Maybe there are other ways to achive HTTPS for my app, in this technology stack.

Comment: 1. *"It looks like nginx has problem forwarding with POST request only"*: You didn't show us how you configure the https. However,  my best guess is:  it is not caused by Nginx itself, but caused by the way you send the `POST` request. It's likely that you send a **`http`** post instead of a **`https`** post within a `https` page.  2. If that's not the case, please show us the nginx logs.

Comment: I used letsencrypt certbot to configure https. Browser indentifies my Page as secure after entering it. Addresing your second question, I have global setting for endpoint address in my angular app. I am posting to https ://mydomain.xx/api/login which shoudl be redirected to backend.

Comment: So if the browser has already sent the post request, could you please show us the logs of nginx as well as the the kestrel logs?

Comment: Looks like problem is solved. To be clear - I did not change anything, just booted up containers to check logs for you, and that's it - logging and basically everything is working over https. I don't know what happend, maybe some old content was cattched somewhere and I wasn't able to work on current changes, honestly, I don't really get that. Nevertheless, thanks for your time and willigness to help.